# Implicit declaration of all function with param (int&, int&)

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

> I am getting an error in the following program

```
   #include<stdio.h>   
        void func(int &x,int &y){
        }
        int main(){
            int a=10,b=6;

            func(a,b);
            return 0;
        }
```

> Error:
>
> prog.c:2: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token prog.c: In
>   function ‘main’: prog.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function
>   ‘func’
>
> but when I am changing function parameter type from (&) to (*) or any
>   other type then it is working properly.
>
> Like this:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    void func(int *x,int *y){

    }
    int main(){
        int a=10,b=6;
        func(&a,&b);
        return 0;
    }
```

> Thanks in advance.
>
> Nks

Comment: That's right, C doesn't have references.

Comment: as chris says you can't use reference(ie &)in c. c only supports pointers. no references.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the compiler error since you didn't write valid C code. `(int &x,int &y)` doesn't make any sense, it looks like you are trying to use C++ references in C.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pass by reference in `C`, you are using `C++` syntax in your code, for `C` your code should be as you mentioned in 2nd Block.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference is not allowed in C.. The second block code is the right thing..

When you are passing address of variables in your **actual parameters**, you need to collect them in pointer variables in your **formal parameters** in C language..

```
func(&x, &y)    // actual parameters

void func(int *x, int *y)    //formal parameters
```